# Reading large text files into SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've got to read and put text into a SQL Server table.

I initially started with a BULK INSERT, but I have the problem that I don't now the encoding of the files and so the BULK sometimes outputs some errors.

Then, I choose to make through a C# Console Aplication, and everything works fine, except when I have large files. To about 300-400 MB, I don't have any problem, but above that, I'm getting a OOM error.

Here's my code:

```
static void Main()
    {
        string fullFileName = @"C:\Temp\410.4604";
        string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullFileName);
        string table = FileName.Substring(0, 3);
        Console.WriteLine("Iniciou às: " + inicio);

        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        data.Clear();
        data.Columns.Add("Text");
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(fullFileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read))
        using (System.IO.BufferedStream bs = new System.IO.BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                data.Rows.Add(line);
            }
        }

        var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(myConn);
        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(myProc, conn);
        insertCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter insParam1 = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", data);
        insParam1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        SqlParameter insParam2 = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", table);

        conn.Open();
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        data.Clear();
        data = null;
        GC.Collect();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Any ideas? Or advices to improve this?
Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried `SqlBulkCopy`? Reading the entire file in a `DataTable` won't work (since `DataTable` is horrendously inefficient, memory-wise) but you can do batch inserts of a limited number of rows at a time.

Comment: Have you considered making this a 64 bit application? And using it on a computer with enough ram to avoid the OOM issues - fastest solution. 4gb and more should be standard anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The problem is not inserting on the DB, but putting the values on the datatable, so, how can I do a SqlBulkCopy directly from a file or reading the file in a given number of lines at a time?

Comment: I'm reading about SqlBulkCopy, and there's no way of inserting without constructing a Datatable. Any help. please!!!!!